# drag and dorp outlook email to browser without third party library

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, drag-and-drop

I'm creating the drop zone using html and java script. When I'm dropped outlook mail only get this

```
{"From  Subject Received    Size    Categories  
Shiza Khaliq    Re: Resume for Dot Net Developer    5/10/2019   49 KB       }
```

not get the message and attachments.

Get dropped outlook email To, From, subject, message and attachment into browser without any third party library purely in html and javascript or asp.net mvc app is actual problem.

Comment: <script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    alert(data);
}
</script>

    <p>Drag the W3Schools image into the rectangle:</p>

    <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) (and get a badge). Your question lacks any attempt at solving this problem on your own. The idea is for you to try to get something to work and then come here with specific problems you are unable to resolve. Taking the tour and reading about [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center will provide all the information you need.